# Idea android sdk set up

Tags: android, sdk

When I installed android sdk in idea, the network did not pass and idea was stuck. So I shut down the idea and removed directory "Android/Sdk". But when I set up my proxy and try to run this again. "Android SDK - (installed)" always there, and the set up can't be done. 
I've tried to reinstall idea, but didn't work. I want to know how idea find out if the sdk installed and fix this problem.

[image: It looks]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some problems with my proxy. It has problems communicates with Idea.